# How to use variables that were declared in other ActionListener events

Tags: java, error-handling, actionlistener

I am having problems with variables in ActionListener events. I am writing a program that encrypts and decrypts files by creating and encrypting/decrypting a formatted string that contains the text in the file using a password defined by the user, then writing it to the file. My problem occurs in my ActionListeners. Here is my code:

```
private void buttonEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    int retVal = selectFile.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (retVal == selectFile.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        java.io.File theFile = selectFile.getSelectedFile();
        dialogEncryptPassword.setVisible(true);
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(theFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}                                             

private void buttonOKEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    String password = passwordEncrypt.getText();
    try {
        DESKeySpec key = new DESKeySpec(password.getBytes());
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    CryptString crypt = new CryptString(KeyFactory.generateSecret(key));
    String encryptedString = crypt.encryptBase64(everything);
    dialogEncryptPassword.dispose();
}
```

I am getting a cannot find symbol on the two lines where it says:

```
CryptString crypt = new CryptString(KeyFactory.generateSecret(key));
String encryptedString = crypt.encryptBase64(everything);
```

This is because the string "everything" was defined in the previous ActionListener event, and I don't know how to access variables that were defined in other events. I don't know why it can't find the symbol "key", since it was declared in the same event. Some of my code may not be correct, because my IDE made me reformat my code using try/catch clauses. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Santiago

Comment: you can't. declare them in the class and use them as class variables.

Comment: It's in the try block. So it only visible within that. You have to declare it outside and instantiate it in the try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the `"everything"` as global variable for the class in the class,so don't declare the variable `"everything"` inside the method.

Just do like this

```
public class yourclassname
{
String everything="";

private void buttonEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
//and do you stuff here
}

private void buttonOKEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
//and do you stuff here
}                                           
}
```